# XML Sample Generator - Unable to cast object of type

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, xsd

I am attempting to write a function that makes use of Microsoft's XMLGen library in order to produce an XML document based on a provided Schema. [For reference, I was trying to follow the project on this MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

I ended up translating the project to Visual Basic and while the code builds fine, it throws an exception at run time; "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter'" during XmlWriter.Create()

I thought the XmlWriter.Create() method created a new XmlWriter instance, so I'm not sure why it's attempting to cast an XmlWellFormedWriter.

```
 Public Function CreateXmlFromSchema(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click        

    Dim fDialog As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
    fDialog.Filter = "XML Document (.xml)|*.xml"

    If (fDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

        Dim xStringWriter As New StringWriter()
        Dim xTextWriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(xStringWriter)

        Try

            xTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create("myTextXML.xml")

            xTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

            Dim xQualifiedName As XmlQualifiedName = New XmlQualifiedName("envelope", "mySchema.xsd")

            Dim xSampleGen As XmlSampleGenerator = New XmlSampleGenerator("mySchema.xsd", xQualifiedName)

            xSampleGen.WriteXml(xTextWriter)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)

        Finally
            xTextWriter.Flush()
            xTextWriter.Close()

        End Try

    End If

    Return True

End Function
```

I have no idea what's going wrong, but any and all help will be much appreciated.

If there's a different/better method of creating an XML file based on a schema, I'm all ears. I'm relatively new to working with the XML libraries, and haven't had any formal training.

Comment: Schema really doesn't need to be part of a writer.  The code should generate valid results.  So validating after you generate is usually sufficient.  There are lot of methods for writing in Net.  Do you have a sample of what the actual xml will look like?  Please post.

Comment: I'm not attempting to validate an XML file from the XSD, but rather create an XML from blank based on the detail of the XSD document.

Comment: Since you sort of asked for other methods, you know Visual Studio can generate a sample from the XML Schema Explorer by right-clicking a node, right?

Comment: I'm aware of that functionality, but how can I translate that from a developer right-clicking in a development window, and a user doing the same from a front-end application? Is there a programmatic way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the XmlSampleGenerator class, but this should get you past your current error by not using the StringWriter:

```
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
settings.Indent = True
Dim xTextWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("myTextXML.xml", settings)

Dim xQualifiedName As XmlQualifiedName = New XmlQualifiedName("envelope", "mySchema.xsd")

Dim xSampleGen As XmlSampleGenerator = New XmlSampleGenerator("mySchema.xsd", xQualifiedName)

xSampleGen.WriteXml(xTextWriter)
```

Comment: Sorry, the XmlSampleGenerator is a Microsoft.XML library, so I assumed it didn't need to be listed. As far as your suggestion, I tried using the .Create() method in the declaration and received the same error message.

Comment: I found the class in NuGet, and it actually works with an XSD I had laying around.

Comment: Oh man, this was the solution that got things working. Turns out declaring xTextWriter as an XmlWriter instead of XmlTextWriter, and using XmlSettings to set formatting instead of the XmlTextWriter.formatting class, was my answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have a follow-up question: you said you were able to get this to work, but did you open the document that was created afterwards? I managed to debug the issue with your help, but the document seems to be vanishing after the code runs.

Have I left out something vital to saving the doc?

Comment: My test was a console app with an XSD I randomly picked, and it made a correct XML in the bin/debug folder as one would expect and just exited. The file looked fine in VS after the run completed.